# How to intgerate jsreprt in php? in ubuntu

Tags: javascript

I installed php and apache on my ubuntu system. Now I want to integrate js report on php. I tried using node js and that is working. How to do it?

Comment: Please provide more information about this and add more details to your question. What exactly have you tried? What isn't working and what do you want to get working?

Comment: I din try anything actually. I have developed a website in php. Now I want to generate report. How to generate report using jsreport?

Comment: I don't know much about jsreport, but I think this may help you: https://jsreport.net/learn

Comment: ok. thankyou. @CodeFox